# OpenFDA report_date for Food/Enforcement doesn't seem to work after 9/23/2015

Tags: openfda

I am getting 0 results for any ranges after 9/23/2015.

See last day of results here: https://api.fda.gov/food/enforcement.json?search=report_date:[20150923+TO+20160106]

No results from 9/24 on: https://api.fda.gov/food/enforcement.json?search=report_date:[20150924+TO+20160106]

Did the report_date property become deprecated? I am using report_date in my site's (https://defender.ionep.io) queries to get the previous 90 days -- reporting 0 results at the moment.

Also you can see in the example enforcements graph there are no results after 9/2015 https://open.fda.gov/food/enforcement/

Comment: This bug has been fixed. Thanks for finding it! The data is up-to-date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for catching this one. It is true for all of the enforcement endpoints (food, drug and device).

The link on the FDA that we are crawling is dead (it hangs). There is a bug in pipeline code that shows the enforcement step as complete even though the download of the XML file is timing out. I will get that fixed right now. I will also contact the FDA to make sure they know about the broken link.

Once the link works again, I re-run the enforcement pipelines retroactive to 2015-09-30 (they are weekly reports).

Thanks again.

UPDATE: Please note that this bug has been fixed and the data has been reloaded so that it is up-to-date. 
https://api.fda.gov/food/enforcement.json?search=report_date:[20150924+TO+20160106] now yields results.